# Lufthansa transit at Frankfurt on the way from Chennai to Atlanta, are two hours enough?

Tags: air-travel, transit, airports, frankfurt

I am traveling from Chennai to Atlanta. M first flight is to Frankfurt reaches at 8 30 AM. My second flight is scheduled at 10 45 AM.

Will the two hours transit time enough for boarding my second flight.

What should be my do's and dont's?

Update

Its more than enough. I was able to make it without any tension.

Comment: Are you looking to find out whether 2:15 is enough time to make a connection?

Comment: @Karlson: yes..

Comment: @karthick Thanks for coming back! You could describe your experience in an answer instead of editing the question (it's easy to overlook…)

Answer (score 1):

Legal [minimum connecting time](http://airtravel.about.com/od/airports/a/mincnxdtog.htm) from international to international flights at Frankfurt is 45 minutes, so you should be fine.

I assume you have a valid US visa?  If not, you will need a transit visa for Germany (Schengen).

Comment: This also assumes that it's all on one ticket, so the airline will help you out if your inbound flight is late. On two tickets, and especially two non-changable tickets, you might want to allow more time

Comment: @jpatokal: I have a valid visa.Thanks for the answer.