# Transfer time in Frankfurt airport

Tags: short-connections, connecting-flights, fra

I am flying on September 2 from Rome, Italy to Orlando, Florida through Frankfurt, Germany. Both flights are on Lufthansa. How much transfer time do I need?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Minimum connection time at Frankfurt Airport](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/52311/minimum-connection-time-at-frankfurt-airport-for-an-international-to-schengen-tr), [Lufthansa transit at Frankfurt, are two hours enough?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/30890/lufthansa-transit-at-frankfurt-on-the-way-from-chennai-to-atlanta-are-two-hours), [One hour Lufthansa transit time in Frankfurt](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/35311/one-hour-lufthansa-transit-time-in-frankfurt-from-bangalore-to-dublin)

Comment: Also, since "both flights are on Lufthansa" - if they have been booked as a single trip, Lufthansa considers whatever connection time is given, to be enough...